# Unable to install ADT in eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am getting error:

> > Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
> >       Software being installed: Android Native Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)
> >       Missing requirement: Android Native Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires 'org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Windows 7 Professional 64Bit.

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.(32 Bit).
I wanted to install this only through Offline. Because i wanted to send it to my friend.
No issues on Android SDK.
I have Tried the solution by enabling only http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
and https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ remaining its disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deselect the Native Development Toolkit in your installation selection in Eclipse. You don't want that. It is for writing C code used in Android applications and it is absolutely not needed for Android beginners or to write a normal Android application.

Comment: Thanks for the info..! Worked.. :)

Comment: Thanks for this information - I just tried installing this plugin for hours (running into the same problem) although not needing it... It seems I can stop trying and simply install the Developer Tools :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you check the box 'contact all update sites during install to find required software'. This prevented my default juno 64bit install from adding ADT. I'm not sure how you would identify the sites used for the additional dependent libraries being pulled in for your friend though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same problem but with a different package. Starting Eclipse as an admin solved it for me